# Failed to install Oracle database 18 XE in Amazon AWS with 'Amazon Linux 2' AMI

Tags: linux, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel

I am trying to install Oracle database 18XE in the AWS I took which has Amazon Linux 2 as the AMI.
However It throws an error saying

```
           Requires: /etc/redhat-release
```

adding the whole screenshot here
[image]

What does this mean? Any help? I did not find any source which says Oracle database 18XE does not support Amazon Linux 2 and only supports Red-Hat Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oracle Documentation for Oracle 18XE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/system-requirements.html) does not list Amazon Linux 2 as a supported operating system.

```
The following Linux x86-64 kernels are supported:

Oracle Linux 7.5 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 5: 4.14.35-1818.5.3.el7uek.x86_64 or later
Oracle Linux 7.2 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4: 4.1.12-32.2.3.el7uek.x86_64 or later
Oracle Linux 7 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 3: 3.8.13-35.3.1.el7uek.x86_64 or later
Oracle Linux 7 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64  or later

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 or later

Oracle Linux 6.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 2: 2.6.39-400.211.1.el6uek.x86_64or later
Oracle Linux 6.6 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 3: 3.8.13-44.1.1.el6uek.x86_64 or later
Oracle Linux 6.8 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4: 4.1.12-37.6.2.el6uek.x86_64 or later
Oracle Linux 6.4 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel: 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 or later

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4: 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 or later

SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1: 3.12.49-11.1 or later

Review the system requirements section for a list of minimum package requirements.
```

Comment: Amazon Linux 2 is not a separate operating system, but just a modified version of Red Hat  Enterprise Linux created by amazon for its AWS. Source: https://linuxhint.com/what_is_amazon_linux_2/